# Python fill a list with values

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to fill a list with values in python and unsure on how to do it. In Java I would use `array.fills` but I do not think Python has a similar function to that.

Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np

# inserts string
def insert_sequence(str1, str2, int):
    str1_split1 = str1[:int]
    str1_split2 = str1[int:]
    new_string = str1_split1 + str2 + str1_split2
    return new_string
   
#converts to hexadecimal formatting 
def convertAddressToHex(address):
    if address < 0:
        address = address
        address = (1 << 20) + address
    else:
        if (address & (1 << (20 - 1))) != 0:
            address = address - (1 << 20)
    address = hex(address)  # converts to hexadecimal format after calculating 2's complement
    if len(address) == 3:
        return insert_sequence(address, '00', 2)
    if len(address) == 4:
        return insert_sequence(address, '0', 2)
    if len(address) == 5:
        return address
    if len(address) > 5:
        return address[0:5]

memArray = [[None for _ in range(17)] for _ in range(256)]  
for i in range(0, 4095, 16):
  for j, row in enumerate(memArray):
    for i, _ in enumerate(row):
        memArray[j][i//16] = "0000" + convertAddressToHex(i)

print(np.matrix(memArray))
```

This isn't getting my desired output though. I want only the first "column" of the list to have ordered hex values like this:

```
[  000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  010,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  020,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  030,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  040,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  050,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  060,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  070,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  080,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  090,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  0A0,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  0B0,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  0C0,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  0D0,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  0E0,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
[  0F0,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000,  0000]
```

Comment: What output to you wish ?

Comment: @azro I have edited to include desired output

Answer (score 1):

Here is a block of code that should do what you are looking for:

```py
cols = 17
rows = 16

arr = []

for row_index in range(rows):
    row = ["0000"] * cols
    row[0] = f"{row_index*16:04X}"
    arr.append(row)

print(arr)
```

This part: `["0000"] * cols` yields a list of length `cols` where each element is `"0000"`.

Answer (score 0):

you could always do

```
for j, row in enumerate(memArray):
    for i, _ in enumerate(row):
        memArray[j][i] = "0000"
```

Enumerate will both go through every row in memArray, but also keep count of which one its on so [j][i] will be unique for every loop and will hit every element in the array